# in Dockerfile, how to copy node_modules installed by pnpm?

Tags: docker, sveltekit, pnpm

In PNPM repositories, `node_modules` have many hard links(not symbolic links) of packages to the local .pnpm store.

Now I need to make a `Dockerfile` with a multi-stage building process for my SveltKit repo,

and I am stuck with copying `node_modules` folder from my `builder` to my `deployer` docker image below:

```
FROM node:18.16.0-alpine AS builder
RUN npm install -g pnpm
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN pnpm build
RUN pnpm prune --prod

FROM node:18.16.0-alpine AS deployer
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build build/
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY package.json .
EXPOSE 5173
CMD [ "node", "build" ]
```

Because PNPM is not like NPM. Direct copying the `node_modules` folder will not work.

I have tried to convert the `pnpm-lock.yaml` into `package-lock.json` by `npm i --package-lock-only`, but it took a very long time then failed with this error message: `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'dev')`.

What is the proper solution or workaround?

Comment: Are they hard links or symbolic links?  I'd expect hard links would work fine (they basically are normal files) but I could see symlinks being problematic.

Comment: The documentation suggests a [`pnpm deploy`](https://pnpm.io/cli/deploy) command for use in images, but it's not totally clear to me what it does.  The documentation [suggests](https://pnpm.io/motivation) hard links and not symbolic links, which you should be able to just `COPY --from`.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are correct. `COPY --from` works fine. See my answer below. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about use Linux `cp -rL` command to deal with hard links/symbolic links:

```
RUN cp -rL node_modules node_modules2
RUN rm -r node_modules
RUN mv node_modules2 node_modules
```

But that is not an efficient way to solve it.

Thanks for @DavidMaze. PNPM does use hard links and it seems to work fine with Docker COPY command. Here is a very contrived Dockerfile I tried and it works!

```
FROM node:18.16.0-alpine AS base
RUN npm install -g pnpm
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./
RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile

FROM node:18.16.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=base /app/node_modules ./node_modules
EXPOSE 5173
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

As the above Dockerfile is not a proper way to build a SvelteKit image, you have to comment out those below in your .dockerignore:

```
#.svelte-kit
#**/.env
```

To build the image:

```bash
docker build . -t project1:v2
docker run -p5173:5173 -p 24678:24678 project1:v2
```

Answer (score 1):

I altered the example from the [pnpm docs](https://pnpm.io/docker) on docker to work for Sveltekit:

```
FROM node:20-alpine AS base
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN mkdir /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml /app
COPY prisma /app
WORKDIR /app

FROM base AS prod-deps
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --silent --prod --frozen-lockfile --ignore-scripts

FROM base AS build
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --silent --frozen-lockfile --ignore-scripts
RUN pnpm prisma generate
COPY . /app
RUN pnpm check
RUN pnpm run build


FROM base AS production
COPY --from=prod-deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules/@prisma/client ./node_modules/@prisma/client
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client* ./node_modules/.pnpm/
COPY --from=build /app/build /app/build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "build/index.js" ]
```